# Crosstab conditional format font to hide with crNoColor

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, conditional-statements, crosstab

I'm using Crystal Reports 2013 sp1 version 14.1.1.1036. I have a crosstab on the report and I need to add a row of blank boxes at the bottom of the crosstab so I'm including a row with -999.9999 in the summarized fields section so I get the extra row in the crosstab, then I want to conditionally format the fonts to crNoColor if the value = -999.9999. I'm using the following:

```
if cdbl({spdv_BottlingAnalysis.Analysis Result}) = -999.9999 then crNoColor
```

But the -999.9999 still shows up. I've tried using strings instead of cdbl. I've tried the Highlighting Expert (which does work for hiding the row headers but for some reason not the summarized fields).

Is there a way to get this formatting to work? Or is there a better way to get the row of blank boxes at the bottom? The crosstab needs to exclude blank values from the data so I need something in those boxes to hide.

Comment: I found that if I didn't suppress the Column Totals on the cross tab I could suppress all the total cell text and got the results I wanted. I didn't need to add the extra row at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I didn't suppress the Column Totals on the cross tab I could suppress all the total cell text and got the results I wanted. I didn't need to add the extra row at all